# What are the differences between LocalCluster and dask-worker

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

In case it matters, everything I describe is happenning under windows.
So, I have a graph of tasks that I want to run using dask.distributed.
If I use a LocalCluster, like this, everything runs fine :

```
cluster: LocalCluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=18, processes=True)
client = Client(cluster)
```

processes=True seems to be paramount, since if I set it to False, I have some errors about memory threshold being reached, and the code seems to stall.

However, if I start a dask-scheduler, and a dask-worker on the very same machine, I encounter a KilledWorker exception.

```
client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')
```

My worker apparently dies at a semi-random point, and get restarted and dies again, up to the point where it is decided that its is faulty and should not be used any more.

So, I wonder what the difference is between a LocalCluster and a dask-worker running on the local machine ? From all the doc I've read, that should be more or less the same, shouldn't it ? Unless there is an option I should pass to dask-worker that has the same behaviour than processes=True for the LocalCluster ?

**UPDATE**
I refactored my code to make it portable. I started some workers on a WSL Debian, with `dask-worker --nworkers=18 --nthreads=1 192.168.1.30:8786` and it ran flawlessly, with no worker dying, and about the same amount of time than with a LocalCluster. The refactored code still exhibits the KilledWorker behaviour when I run it with some Windows workers started with the exact same command.
So it now seems pretty obvious to me there is something windows-specific here, although I have no idea what... (and running my workers in WSL is more of a hack in my process than a practical solution ...)

Comment: What exact command are you using to start the worker on the command line? You will see that it has *many* options.

Comment: I run "dash-worker localhost:8786" and I've tried many combinations of values for --nthread and --nworkers. I've also tried increasing --death-timeout to a very high value, and specifiying various levels of --memory-limit (which shouldn't be a problem on my toy code). 
Basically my question could be reformulated as : What arguments should I pass to my dash-worker to get the exact same  behaviour than when I start a local cluster, which runs perfectly ?